# Intuition - strong markov property vs. stationary

Tags: random, markov-process, stationary-processes

I try to gain an intuition what a difference between Markov property, strong Markov property and stationarity of a random process is. I'm physicist with no strong background in stochastic theory. I have found many of the questions here concerning strong Markov property, but I still didn't get it. In particular I don't understand:

- why the time-continuity play a role by Markov<=>strong Markov?
- how the Markov process can at all not be stationary (for example by fixing the initial condition)?
- By some [examples](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43833/a-markov-process-which-is-not-a-strong-markov-process/43838#43838) of non-strong Markov but Markov processes for me it is a difference between stationary/not stationary process (what is false if I get it right).

I would be happy if somebody could explain me the matter.